# Determining All the Nodes to the Left of a Given Node (Python)

Tags: python, tree, nodes

I'm new to Python and am trying to return a list of all nodes that are to the left of a given node in an ordered tree (i.e. descendants of the parent but only on the left). I want to say something like if **there exists** a sibling which is less than the given node, return all of it's descendants. However, I don't quite know how to do that in python. I've provided my code below (all referenced methods work).

```
def LeftOfNode(node, T):
    if [x < node for x in Siblings(node, T)]:
        left = []
        for x in Siblings(node, T):
            if x < node:
                left += Descendants(x, T)
        left += [Parent(node, T)]
        return left
    else:
        return LeftOfNode(Parent(node, T), T)
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: first bug is the statement `if [x < node for x in Siblings(node, T)]` will always return True. Try to use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) or [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

Comment: what is your first if statement checking? is it just that there are siblings because it will pretty much always return True unless Siblings is empty

Comment: i think you probably meant `any(x < node for x in Siblings(node, T))` ?